# How to get/update aliases with go-elasticsearch?

Tags: go, elasticsearch

I'm using the `go-elasticsearch` and I need to use the operations in the [Aliases API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/aliases.html):

- `GET _alias/my-alias-name` to get the information on an alias
- `POST _aliases` to add multiple index names to an alias in an atomic operation

I can't find the representations of these APIs in the `go-elasticsearch` client, is there any alternative way to make a request to these endpoints with the library, or I just need to use a plain HTTP client only for these methods?

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a way to do it, the Aliases API is inside the Indices API:

- `GET _alias/my-alias-name`: we can get the alias information using the `GetAlias()` method, building a request like this:

```golang
res, err := s.client.Indices.GetAlias(
    s.client.Indices.GetAlias.WithName("my-alias-name"),
    s.client.Indices.GetAlias.WithContext(context.Background()),
)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
// ...parse response
```

- `POST _aliases` to add or delete indices to aliases in an single operation we can use `UpdateAliases()`:

```golang
type UpdateAliasRequest struct {
    Actions []map[string]*UpdateAliasAction `json:"actions"`
}

// UpdateAliasAction represents an action in the Elasticsearch Aliases API.
type UpdateAliasAction struct {
    Index string `json:"index"`
    Alias string `json:"alias"`
}

updateActions := make([]map[string]*UpdateAliasAction, 0)

removeAction := make(map[string]*UpdateAliasAction)
removeAction["remove"] = &UpdateAliasAction{
    Index: "old-index-00",
    Alias: "my-alias-name",
}
updateActions = append(updateActions, removeAction)

addAction := make(map[string]*UpdateAliasAction)
addAction["add"] = &UpdateAliasAction{
    Index: "new-index-00",
    Alias: "my-alias-name",
}
updateActions = append(updateActions, addAction)

jsonBody, err := json.Marshal(&UpdateAliasRequest{
        Actions: updateActions,
})
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}


// make API request
res, err := s.client.Indices.UpdateAliases(
    bytes.NewBuffer(jsonBody),
    s.client.Indices.UpdateAliases.WithContext(context.Background()),
)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
// ...parse response
```